# Can you nest a lightning data service component inside a parent component?

Tags: lightning, lightning-data-service

I've read the component developer guide regarding data service components, but I'm not sure if nesting is supported.  I am getting the following error when a data service component is a child, but it works fine on the page itself: 
Uncaught Action failed: c:ResetASDBtn$controller$resetASD [Cannot read property 'CloseDate' of null]

Parent:

```
 <aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="parentRecordId" type="Id" />
<c:ResetASDBtn recordId="{!v.parentRecordId}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Child:

```
<aura:component  implements="force:hasRecordId">
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
<aura:attribute name="opportunityRecord" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="resetDate" type="Date" default="2100-12-01"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordLoadError" type="String"/>
<force:recordData aura:id="oppRecordUpdate"
    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
    fields="CAREStatusListView__c,CloseDate"
    targetFields="{!v.opportunityRecord}"
    mode="EDIT"
    recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdated}" />

<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Reset ASD"  onclick="{!c.resetASD }" /> 
//...additional logic
```

Child Controller:

```
//additional logic
resetASD: function(component, event, helper) {
    var oId = component.get("v.recordId");
    component.set("v.opportunityRecord.CloseDate", component.get("v.resetDate"));
    component.find("oppRecordUpdate").saveRecord($A.getCallback(function(saveResult) {
        if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
            console.log("Save completed successfully.");
        } else if (saveResult.state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            console.log("User is offline, device doesn't support drafts.");
        } else if (saveResult.state === "ERROR") {
            console.log('Problem saving record, error: ' + 
                       JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
        } else {
            console.log('Unknown problem, state: ' + saveResult.state + ', error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
        }
    }));
}
```

})

Comment: can you please try to reduce your code to the relevant parts of your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parent attribute name also needs to be record id:

```
<aura:component 
implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" 
access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
<c:ResetASDBtn recordId="{!v.recordId}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Works just fine.